# Splitting string using ArcGIS Pro field calculator

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser, text

Generating an error in what should be a basic field calculation.

I have two text fields: MyAddress and AreaName. Both are text. I would like to use MyAddress to populate AreaName with everything except the street type. E.g. "Eagle View Ln" just becomes "Eagle View".

The code that I thought would work:

```
!MyAddress!.split(" ")[:-1]
```

I've tried it using the code block, same result.

This generates error [001156](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.7/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/001001-010000/tool-errors-and-warnings-01151-01175-001156.htm). The help documentation suggests it may be a disagreement between field type or length. I have double checked both, and been trying with a few different fields. It seems to be something with the indexing, as str() generates a string version of he appropriate list.

```
str(!MyAddress!.split(" ")[:-1])
```

returns ["Eagle", "View"] in the field.

But basic indexing seems to work on the field:

```
!MyAddress![:-1]
```

Returns Eagle View L

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're really close.

An extra step is needed to rejoin the list values back together. Enter '[Join](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_join.asp)'

```
myAddress = "Eagle View Ln"
myAddressAsList = myAddress.split(" ")[:-1] ## Returns a list: ['Eagle', 'View']
myNewAddressAsString = " ".join(tempList) ### Returns a string: 'Eagle View'

# Or simplified to just one line would be:
otherNewAddress = " ".join(myAddress.split(" ")[:-1])
```

Lastly, if calculated using a Code-Block in ArcGIS Pro's "Calculate Field" tool, it might look something like this:

[image: Calculate Field example]