# Separate ArcGIS Pro field of (a + b) into two fields (a) AND (b)

Tags: arcgis-pro, fields-attributes

I have a dataset

[image]

What I am trying to do is pull out the street names from the original field. Any ideas?

Comment: Use then python split method, then join the list items back together. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/400957/splitting-string-using-arcgis-pro-field-calculator?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

use the `Calculate Field` tool; for FieldName
select StreetName_1 first

Choose Expression Type **Python**

Enter this expression:
**!Intersecti![0,!Intersecti!.find("&") - 2]**

This should select the substring from position 0 through to just before the space before the ampersand and apply it to the StreetName_1 field.

Next, do the same operation but for StreetName_2:

Enter this expression:
**!Intersecti![!Intersecti!.find("&") + 2]**

This will select the substring beginning 2 characters after the ampersand through the end of the Intersecti string field.